# Querying OCB from JavaScript (WireCloud)

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to get *type* fields for each attribute of my entities. Quering Orion and getting entities is not the problem (I do this through NGSI Source widget) but the way getting these parameters.

From NGSI Source (usual suscription to Orion instance):

```
 var doInitialSubscription = function doInitialSubscription() {

    this.subscriptionId = null;

    this.ngsi_server = MashupPlatform.prefs.get('ngsi_server');
    this.ngsi_proxy = MashupPlatform.prefs.get('ngsi_proxy');
    this.connection = new NGSI.Connection(this.ngsi_server, {
        ngsi_proxy_url: this.ngsi_proxy
    });

    var types = MashupPlatform.prefs.get('ngsi_entities').split(new RegExp(',\\s*'));
    var entityIdList = [];
    var entityId;
    for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        entityId = {
            id: '.*',
            type: types[i],
            isPattern: true
        };
        entityIdList.push(entityId);
    }
    var attributeList = null;
    var duration = 'PT3H';
    var throttling = null;
    var notifyConditions = [{
        'type': 'ONCHANGE',
        'condValues': MashupPlatform.prefs.get('ngsi_update_attributes').split(new RegExp(',\\s*'))
    }];
    var options = {
        flat: true,
        onNotify: handlerReceiveEntity.bind(this),
        onSuccess: function (data) {
            this.subscriptionId = data.subscriptionId;
            this.refresh_interval = setInterval(refreshNGSISubscription.bind(this), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2);  // each 2 hours
            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
                this.connection.cancelSubscription(this.subscriptionId);
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this)
    };
    this.connection.createSubscription(entityIdList, attributeList, duration, throttling, notifyConditions, options);
};
 var handlerReceiveEntity = function handlerReceiveEntity(data) {
    for (var entityId in data.elements) {
        MashupPlatform.wiring.pushEvent("entityOutput", JSON.stringify(data.elements[entityId]));
    }
};
```

To MyWidget:

```
MashupPlatform.wiring.registerCallback("entityInput", function (entityString) {
    var entity;
    entity = JSON.parse(entityString);
    id = entity.id;
    type = entity.type;
    for(var attr in entity){
        attribute = entity[attr];
    }
```

I'm trying to code something similar to obtain the value of *type* fields. How can I do that? (I'm sure it's quite easy...)

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the content of the `entityString` variable to have a better understanding of the case, please?

Comment: @fgalan I found the reason, this is the content: `{"id":"387243781","type":"MyApp","BAT":"65","value1":"351","value2":"0.023","value3":"0.039","value4":"37.375476","value5":"-5.989363","date":"23/11/2014 13:26:27","address":"Parque de María Luisa 41013 Sevilla"}` . I'm only retrieving name and value fields of entities. I attached also the way I'm suscribing to changes through Orion. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make use of the current NGSI source operator implementation (at least v3.0.2) if you want to get the type metadata of attributes as the NGSI source makes use of the `flat` option (discarding that info).

We are studying updating this operator to allow creating subscriptions without using the `flat` option. The main problem here is that other components expect the data provided by this operator being provided in the format returned when using the `flat` option. I will update this answer after analysing deeper the issue.